# Parametric equations of surfaces of revolution

Tags: complex-analysis, surfaces

I need to find a parametrization for the following two surfaces:

(i) The surface obtained by revolving the curve $z = f(x),\ (a \lt x \lt b)$ in the $xz$ plane, around the $z$ axis, where $a \gt 0$.

The solution states that $f(u,v) = (v \cos u,v \sin u,f(v))^{T}$ with $u \in [0,2\pi)$ and $v \in (a,b)$. The part I'm having difficulty with is why it is $v\cos u$ etc and not $f(v)\cos u$?

The second question is the similar except the curve is revolved around the $x$ axis, $f(x) \gt 0$ (and there are no conditions on $a$ and $b$). But in this case, $f(u,v) = (v,f(v)\sin u,f(v)\cos u)^{T}$ - why is it $f(v)$ now?
I've tried doing a few sketches but it still hasn't clicked.

Comment: If the curve was the single point (v,c) then the revolution would map out a circle of radius v at a height of c, which would have parametrization (vcos(u), vsin(u),c) for u in 0 to 2$\pi$. Now scale up to v in (a, b) and z = f(v) instead of c. Are you sure the second one isn't a revolution around the x-axis?

Comment: Sorry yes, corrected it.

Comment: The radius in the second example will now be f(x). I think the first coordinate in f(u, v) should be v not f(v). Replace v with x and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected that as well.